# How many possible subsets in all possible regressions

Tags: combinatorics, regression

Suppose that there are three candidate predictors, x<sub>1</sub> , x<sub>2</sub>, and x<sub>3</sub>, for a final regression model. Suppose further that the intercept term, β<sub>0</sub> is always included in all the model equations. How many models must be estimated and examined if one applies all possible regressions approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Our models vary based on which predictors are selected to be in a particular model.

How many ways can we make a model with $0$ of the predictors? With $1$? With $2$? With all $3$?

Comment: - 0 predictors give 1 model (only the constant term)
- 1 predictors give 1 model (only x1)
- 2 predictors give 3 possible models (x1, x2 or x1&x2)
- 3 predictors give 7 possible models (x1, x2, x3, x1&x2, x2&x3, x1&x3 or x1&x2&x3)

So in the nth case, what is the amount of models that can be created? 

Is it n!+1?

Comment: Not quite. You have listed out all of the possibilities, but some of them you have listed out more than once. (I see x1 up there three times). When I ask how many models use one predictor, I am referring to the models with x1 only or x2 only or x3 only. Once you have figured out how many models there are for the cases of $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ then you add up the possibilities to get the total

Comment: Alright, sorry if I'm not following, but in that case, we can;
- Use 0 predictor in 1 way
- Use 1 predictor 3 ways
- Use 2 predictors in 3 ways
- Use all 3 predictors in 1 way?

Then would that mean that having 3 predictors we can make 8 different models?

Comment: Yes. This is the correct answer!

Comment: Great, thanks! And in the nth case, how would one approach it then? What would the formula be?

Comment: See that the numbers that cropped up: $1,3,3,1$ correspond to the binomial coefficients $\binom{3}{0}$, $\binom{3}{1}$, $\binom{3}{2}$ , and $\binom{3}{3}$. See if you can use this to figure out the general solution

Comment: I get that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}= 2^n$

Comment: Yup! You got it! And that's the generalized answer for having $n$ predictor variables